# List of shipping on product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display each shipping method on the product page. For example:

> DPD | 10 $ DHL | 15 $ etc etc...

I used a WC() method, but it does not give the results what I want. Flat method/free delivery is not the problem, but I am also using table rate(flexible shipping) and methods don't display price.

i find something like : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252728/display-shipping-methods-to-frontend-as-in-the-admin-panel/47264090#47264090

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409734/display-shipping-cost-on-product-page-woocommerce/47447817#47447817

Unfortunately this solution dosen't display flexible shipping prices(this is important for me).

Comment: You might need to give a little more detail in your question, such as what methods you used and how they didn't work.

Comment: I used wc()-shipping-get shipping methods() etc but this funciton didn't display price of single shipping. I find something like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252728/display-shipping-methods-to-frontend-as-in-the-admin-panel/47264090#47264090 , but still that not fix the problem. (Display price, correctly name of shipping - unfortunately only on flat_rates and free_shipping). I want to display price by weight from flexible shipping by wp-desk :/